# Memory Consistency || Thread interference || Php

Tags: php, magento, memcached

I have a question regarding Memcache and session lock for user session.
I want to lock or do something that will prevent Thread Interference for user session...

We have a situation like so:

If server is at max, user is redirected to "free" server, but a this point some of data are wrong...

So does anybody has any sugestions :?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean, but if you're load balancing servers you need to share sessions between them. You should setup your sessions either in memcache or a database. I understand you're using memcache sessions? If yes what's the problem?

Comment: Session is loaded into memcache and the problem is data consistance, some of data very rarely are stored with wrong values. And i don't know why :/

Answer (score 0):

All your Memcached servers must be listed in your `app/etc/local.xml` file and be the same for each server, that way they will share the session data.

Alternatively - or additionally - a better load balancing policy would be "consistent hashing".  Users would be spread evenly over the available servers and each user would be handled by the same server, and hence, same session.

Comment: Servers are listed in local.xml
Hmmm... i think i will try "consistent hashing"...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I really thought it could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spread your sessions across multiple servers I would recommend using consistent hashing, as it reduces the number of misses when you add/delete servers.

Memcached does not support locking, but I believe a the new [memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) module has a workaround that provides [support for locking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php). I have however not used it yet.